# Smartface gives error while trying to run

Tags: mobile, smartface.io

When I try to run my app on the emulator in Smartface App Studio, I get an error. It so interesting, i tried something to fix it and googled to find a solution lots of times. But i got nothing.

> Checking Android SDK Configuration.
> Searching for Devices...
> Device found: Faea HY509S
> Generating Exporting Packages for Android profile:"Default"
> Pages, JavaScripts files are preparing
> Project resources are preparing
> Datasets are preparing
> Installation packages are creating
> Installing Emulator...
> Application could not install to
> Error Message : pkg: /sdcard/SmartfaceEmulator.apkFailure [INSTALLFAILEDCONTAINER_ERROR]
>   Same issue again? Please refer to Troubleshooting document!
> Sorry, an error occured during launching! Please try to launch from your device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about Manifest configuration.

I guess you changed some part of it. 
There is a manifest entry like `android:installLocation`

it should be auto like;

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

Smartface.io Team